# ASP.NET - Error while trying to enter to my administrator area but everything else works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I'm having this issue while trying to enter to my Administrator area on my ASP.NET project.

This error only comes up when trying to navigate to a certain area ([example](http://prntscr.com/fpoxs9))

**The error that comes up is this:**

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

**Stack Trace:**

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5771923
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +507
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +217
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +75

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +125
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +89
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +29
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +386

**For the record:**
My database and hosting are currently hosted in Azure

**EDIT**

This is my only connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=tcp:wineux.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=wineuxproduction;User ID=*****;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;"
```

I'm currently using Microsoft's Owin service. This is my initial configuration on the db context creation:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("EfDatabase", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I've managed to change the error to [this](http://prntscr.com/fq306g)

The specific error is:

*Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.*

And again, this only happens while accessing my Administrator area.

Comment: Well, the error is specifically stated.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Yes, I know but the thing it's I've tried many solutions and nothing seems to work.

Comment: The weird thing it's that I can navigate the whole site normally but this happens ONLY when I try to enter my admin area.

Comment: There are Security levels for your SQL Server on Azure, Like Firewall, You need to allow your IP to access your SQL Server.

Comment: @NiravMadariya I've done that too. I read that to give access to "everyone" I should do a 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 firewall rule and it gave me access to the whole site except the admin area. Do you know if there are any other rules for me to implement?

Comment: If this error only shows up in some areas of your website, than maybe you have a faulty connection string playing around and causing issues (that I hope is not hardcoded somewhere). Try tracing the code lines where you initiate the connection, and see if you come up with Something.
Hope it helps.